# Edittext values in listview changes to default on screen timeout

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-viewholder

I have a `listview` with `edittext` widgets inside each row. I use a `viewholder` inside my `custom adapter` to keep track of all the views.

But my problem is that when i input a value inside my `edittext`, pause until my screen times out, when you unlock the phone while still in the same `activity`,the default `edittext` value is refilled, overwriting my edits.

I followed this suggestion here [(when listview scroll that time edittext set default value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479178/when-listview-scroll-that-time-edittext-set-default-value) considering that maybe i am not using the `viewholder` right but still facing the same issue. It's like `getView()` keeps getting called, completely redrawing my views.

Any ideas/suggestions on a workaround?

```js
package com.shop.shopOfficer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.shopOfficer.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by steve on 2/15/16.
 */
public class ProductListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    List<ProductModel> mStringFilterList;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ProductModel> modelItems;

    private AddRemoveProductInterface myActivityInterface;

    public ProductListAdapter(Activity activity, List<ProductModel> modelItems, AddRemoveProductInterface myActivityInterface) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.modelItems = modelItems;
        mStringFilterList = modelItems;
        this.myActivityInterface = myActivityInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return modelItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            // inflate the layout
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_item_row, null);
            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            viewHolder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            viewHolder.p = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.p);
            viewHolder.minus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
            viewHolder.add = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);
            viewHolder.quantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.num);
            viewHolder.quantity.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(convertView, position));

            viewHolder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //get the value of edittext
                    //add one item
                    int added_item = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.quantity.getText().toString()) + 1;
                    viewHolder.quantity.setText("" + added_item);
                }
            });
            viewHolder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int removed_item = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.quantity.getText().toString()) - 1;
                    if (removed_item >= 0) {

                        viewHolder.quantity.setText("" + removed_item);
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
            // store the holder with the view.
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // object item based on the position
        final ProductModel m = modelItems.get(position);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(m.getname());
        viewHolder.price.setText("(" + m.getPrice() + ")");
        viewHolder.p.setText(m.getPrice());
        viewHolder.quantity.setTag(m);
        viewHolder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(m.getTQuantity()));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(inflater.getContext(), EditProduct.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", m.getname());
                intent.putExtra("price", m.getPrice());
                intent.putExtra("description", m.getproductDesc());
                intent.putExtra("image_url", m.getImage_url());
                inflater.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<ProductModel> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++)
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getname().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()) ||
                            (mStringFilterList.get(i).getproductDesc().toUpperCase())
                                    .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {


                        ProductModel m = new ProductModel(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getname(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getproductId(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getImage_url(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getPrice(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getproductDesc());

                        filterList.add(m);
                    }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;

                //show no results were picked
                //(myActivityInterface).onSearchEmpty("No results found");
            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            //if(results)
            modelItems = (List<ProductModel>) results.values;
            if (modelItems.size() > 0) {

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                (myActivityInterface).onSearchEmpty("No results found");
            }
        }

    }

    static class ViewHolderItem {

        TextView tvTitle, price, p;
        Button add, minus;
        EditText quantity;
    }

    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        View view;
        int position;

        public MyTextWatcher(View convertView, int position) {
            this.view = convertView;
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            EditText qtyView = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.num);
           // ProductModel m = modelItems.get(position);
            String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
            int quantity = qtyString.equals("") ? 0:Integer.valueOf(qtyString);
            ProductModel m = (ProductModel)qtyView.getTag();
            if(m.getTQuantity() != quantity) {
                m.setTQuantity(quantity);
                String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.p))
                        .getText().toString();
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2))
                        .getText().toString();
                int database_position = 1 + position;
                Log.d("my position", "" + position);
                Log.d("my value", s.toString() + price);
                (myActivityInterface).onAdded(s.toString().trim(), price, database_position, name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Activity code:

```js
public class ProductList extends AppCompatActivity implements AddRemoveProductInterface {

    ListView listView, checkout_listview;
    EditText inputSearch;
    ProductListAdapter adapter;
    ProductCheckoutAdapter checkout_adapter;
    ProductHandler productDB;
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    TextView total;
    String unformatted_number;
    String c_phone, c_zip, c_name, total_amount, checkout_id;
    Boolean c_extras;
    fr.castorflex.android.smoothprogressbar.SmoothProgressBar progbar;
    Button button;
    byte[] b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        total.setText("0.00");
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            //is null
            c_extras = false;
        } else {
            //has extras
            c_extras = true;
            b = extras.getByteArray("picture");
            c_phone = i.getStringExtra("phone");
            c_zip = i.getStringExtra("zip");
            c_name = i.getStringExtra("name");
            total_amount = i.getStringExtra("total_amount");
            checkout_id = i.getStringExtra("checkout_id");
            if (total_amount == null) {
                total.setText("0.00");
            } else {

                total.setText(total_amount);
            }
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), total_amount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        productDB = new ProductHandler(this);
       /* sbv = (SlideBottomPanel) findViewById(R.id.sbv);*/

        progbar = (fr.castorflex.android.smoothprogressbar.SmoothProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prog1);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
       // listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
        checkout_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.checkout_list);
        // insert data into the list before setting the adapter
        // otherwise it will generate NullPointerException  - Obviously
        productListRequest();
        showProductFromTable();
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
               /* ProductList.this.myList.getFilter().filter(cs);*/
                if (cs.length() > 0) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                } else {
                    TextView search = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_results);
                    search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        final LinearLayout animated_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_animated);
        //animating product sold list
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        if (total.getText().toString().equals("0.00")) {
            button.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("JSON PROD:", productDB.composeProductSolddJSONfromSQLite());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomerIdentify.class);
                intent.putExtra("total_sld", unformatted_number);
                //send extras if exist to identify activity
                if (c_extras) {
                    intent.putExtra("picture", b);
                    intent.putExtra("c_phone", c_phone);
                    intent.putExtra("c_extras", c_extras);
                    intent.putExtra("c_zip", c_zip);
                    intent.putExtra("c_name", c_name);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
              
            }
        });
    }

    private void showProductFromTable() {
        //progbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ArrayList<ProductModel> modelArrayList = productDB.loadProduct();
        //adding it to the list view.
        adapter = new ProductListAdapter(this, modelArrayList, this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void productListRequest() {
        progbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String url = "http://shopofficer.com/business/products/api";
        JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("product list response:", response.toString());
                        //listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = obj.getString("name");
                                String price = obj.getString("price");
                                String description = obj.getString("description");
                                String image = obj.getString("image");
                                String product_id = obj.getString("id");
                                /*Log.d("my data is", id + title + description);*/
                                productDB.addProduct(product_id, name, price, description, image, "0");
                                showProductFromTable();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("productlist error",
                        "Error: " + error.getMessage());

              /*  Crouton.makeText(AttendantList.this, "Something went wrong, please retry",
                       Style.ALERT, R.id.anchor).show();*/
                progbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }) {


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("session_id", getapikey());
                return headers;
            }
        };
        ShopOfficer.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache()
                .invalidate(url, true);
        // Adding request to request queue
        ShopOfficer.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_select_product, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        showProductFromTable();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_add_product) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddNewProduct.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdded(String s, String price, int database_position, String name) {

        if (s.equals("")) {
        } else {
            //set total
            Double currentPrice = Double.valueOf(price);
            Double quantity = Double.valueOf(s);
            Double calculated = quantity * currentPrice;
            //Double priceDiff = Double.valueOf(df.format(extPrice - currPrice));
            productDB.update(database_position, "" + calculated);
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
            //add commas thousands
            unformatted_number = String.valueOf(df.format(productDB.getTotalOfAmount()));
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(unformatted_number);
            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
            total.setText("" + formatter.format(amount));
            if (total.getText().toString().equals(".00")) {
                total.setText("0.00");
            }
            //add product sold
            if (quantity < 1) {
                productDB.deleteSingleProductSold(Integer.valueOf(s));
            } else {
                productDB.addSale(database_position, name, String.valueOf(calculated), s);
            }
            if (total.getText().toString().equals("0.00")) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoved(String s) {
        total.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchEmpty(String s) {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        TextView search = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_results);
        search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        search.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the adapter in the lifecycle of your activity?

Comment: In my onCreate() function.

Comment: Can you show your activity code please?

Comment: @Fabio Venturi Pastor done. See my edit.

Comment: Did you try to delete "showProductFromTable()" of onResume()

Comment: I'm sorry, i get your point. I see where i might have gone wrong

Comment: Because youre calling  listView.setAdapter(adapter); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();, so when you unlock your phone probably that function is reseting the listview

Comment: Yes yes i agree. I am showing a dialog when one wants to edit the row, how do i update dynamically without having to reload the entire adapter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106379/discussion-between-fabio-venturi-pastor-and-steve-kamau).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views and the viewholders are only temporarily associated with a row. It means that any edited data needs to be stored elsewhere.
Otherwise the information is lost every time the views are rebuild or reused for a different row, like when scrolling or rebuilding the view.

One possible solution is to add it to the model :

- Add the data (quantity) to the `ProductModel`. (`the_quantity`)
- Add a position attribute to the viewholder (`the_position`).
  This is needed because the listeners are anonymous classes. They see (a copy of) the value of the `position` parameter with the value it had when they were instanciated.
  This is why the compiler sometimes complains that the `position` parameter is not final, and it usually means that something is wrong : You should only reference it outside callbacks.
- UI -> model : Store the edited value in model (in both listeners)

  ```
  public void onClick(View v) {
      //get the value of edittext
      //add one item
      int added_item = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.quantity.getText().toString()) + 1;

      // Store the value in the model
      // We use the position from the viewholder,
      // **not** the method's parameter (which contain 
      // the value when the listener was created)
      modelItems.get(viewHolder.the_position).the_quantity = added_item;

      viewHolder.quantity.setText("" + added_item);
  }
  ```
- Model -> UI : Update the UI each time, not only when the views a created

  ```
  // object item based on the position
  final ProductModel m = modelItems.get(position);
  viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(m.getname());      

  // update the viewholder's position 
  viewHolder.the_position = position;
  viewHolder.quantity.setText("" + m.the_quantity)

  return convertView;
  ```

Comment: i have read up about that but i am unsure of where to edit my code without messing it up. I have edited my code with full adapter code. Please see above.

Comment: Okay i have somehow followed your suggestion. See my full adapter code above

Comment: If I understand correctly you are now updating the quantity view from the model. That looks ok.
`MyTextWatcher` updates the model with the edited values. That looks ok too.
It seems that it also triggers a DB update, based on the position (`database_position`). I think there are 2 problems 
:- the `TextWatcher` contains the (wrong) final position
- anyway the adapter position depends on the filtering.
It would probably be better to use some kind of DB id, stored int the `ProductModel` itself

Comment: I saw that too, i am now using the id that came with the productmodel which is also stored in db

Comment: Are the quantity EditText still reset to 0 ?

Comment: how comes the value is reset to 0 when i filter my items?

Comment: I think the quantity is lost in the `performFiltering()`,  you should copy it in the new `ProductModel` instance (or reuse the same instance)

Comment: I know it's too much to ask, but please can you show me how.

Comment: The filter should create a new list, but can usually reuse the items, in your case try to replace `filterList.add(m);` with `filterList.add(mStringFilterList.get(i));` (without creating the `m` instance)

Comment: It has worked amazing! But with this way I cannot figure out the modelItems.size() when performing search . In short if the result matches it is okay, but if I delete letters during search I get both "no results found" and the list. See publishedResults(..) method in the adapter.

Comment: you should always `notifyDataSetChanged();`  when you replace `modelItems` in  `publishResults()` even when the new list is empty, but I don't really understand why the problem occur when you delete letters

Comment: Nothing was wrong, just had to change my logic abit in my if statement. I appreciate your help man.